# Unmodified F4 no longer summons LaunchPad

Tags: macos, launchpad, keyboard

When I press <kbd>F4</kbd>, it no longer summons LaunchPad. <kbd>F3</kbd> still invokes Mission Control, and the other function keys, without modifiers, have their respective meanings (volume, play, etc), but I can only invoke LaunchPad with my hot corner or the Dock button.

How can I reset this to default behavior?

Comment: When I create a new user, the key works, which suggests it's some Preference file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to `rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist` and log out and back in. I just tried this and it seems to have restored the binding, no hack like FunctionFlip required. My other special keys all work, too. However, I lost my other customized Keyboard Shortcuts, like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> for switching spaces Mission Control. They worked after I re-enabled them.

It looks like `com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist` is the preferences file, and MacOS works fine if it's missing. After I'd edited my Keyboard Shortcuts via the preferences panel that file was recreated and everything's back to normal except Launchpad launches again. Based on a diff of the two plist files I'm guessing the keycode for Launchpad is one of 118, 119, 64, or 65.

I found this solution on a [MacRumors discussion](http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-1215005.html).

Answer (score 2):

To not lose your custom shortcuts, open `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist`, look for the key named "160". Edit it as follows:

[image]

Then Log Out and back in.

Comment: Editing the plist without Property List Editor: `plist=~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist; plutil -convert xml1 $plist; open $plist -a TextEdit`

Comment: Or use TextWrangler, with no conversion commands at all in Terminal

Comment: Maybe the fact the missing build in F5 shortcut was removed from M1 macs, while there's a 'do not disturb' shortcut (as if we need a shortcut for it, how often do you toggle 'do not disturb' anyway?), is some indication that LaunchPad is on the way out. This fix is working, but it keeps breaking again. Some decisions are just beyond me...

Answer (score 1):

I lost the <kbd>F4</kbd> binding too, and after some investigation I got it working again. It's a bit of a hack, but here's what worked:

1. Install [FunctionFlip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/), a free preference pane to modify the function keys.
2. In FunctionFlip click <kbd>F4</kbd>: Launchpad, so it's checked.
3. In System Preferences / Keyboard / Keyboard Shortcuts, doubleclick on the keybinding for Show Launchpad and press <kbd>F4</kbd>.

FunctionFlip should not be necessary: it should be enough to set the binding in Keyboard Shortcuts. The problem is by default the <kbd>F4</kbd> key does not actually send the keycode for <kbd>F4</kbd>, it sends the magic code for LaunchPad. (Just like <kbd>F8</kbd> isn't <kbd>F8</kbd>, it's pause iTunes.) And the Keyboard preferences pane won't let you bind that magic LaunchPad key. FunctionFlip solves the issue by making it so the <kbd>F4</kbd> key really sends <kbd>F4</kbd>.

Note that FunctionFlip is a bit tricky. For it to work, you have to enable System Preferences / Universal Access / Enable access for assistive devices. Also there's a "Start FunctionFliip at Login" preference that you probably want to enable.

The FunctionFlip page points to two tutorials for LaunchPad: [TUAW](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/07/22/make-your-pre-lion-keyboard-work-with-launchpad/) and [Josh Sunshine's](http://www.joshsunshine.me.uk/2011/07/remap-the-dashboard-key-to-launchpad/). Same procedure as I describe above.

Comment: I like that, but don't want to lose F4 as a separate key from LaunchPad. Great workaround, but I'm looking for a fix. As I said, I suspect it's a preference file.

Comment: Please see my edit for a different fix. I think I found your preference file.

Comment: I want to accept this and award the bounty, but can you make your second solution a separate answer? I like them both, and want to up vote them both, but the second is the one I want to document as the best one.

Comment: ok, done. sorry for so many edits!

Answer (score 1):

I have just upgraded from Snow Leopard to El Capitan, and have the F4=Dashboard key on my keyboard.

I have set <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to Launchpad, and turned Dashboard on, in System Preferences > Keyboard, but I wanted them the other way around so Launchpad would default.

I did not want to add anything i.e. FunctionFlip

Thanks to Kentzo's answer above, I downloaded TextWrangler, opened

`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist`

changed Item 1's number from 118 to 130,

logged off, now working as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is pretty weird. The item for *Show Launchpad* has to be checked (but not necessarily assigned to any regular shortcut) for <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to work:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone seeing this in 2017 on a Macbook Pro with touch bar, chances are you are using Spotify and it is the cause of the issue (see [discussion](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Ongoing-Issues/F4-key-does-not-work-on-MacBook-Pro-with-touchbar-if-Spotify-is/idi-p/1552175)). As of this post's date, there isn't a fix. The simplest workaround is to stop using Spotify.