# How come my Launchpad key opens Dashboard instead, and how can I fix it?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard

The answer is not as simple as you might think at first glance; please read the details of my question.

I know the difference between Standard Function keys and Special keys. Standard Function keys are <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, etc. whereas the Special keys are  "Decrease Brightness, "Increase Brightness", "Mute" and so on.

When the "Use all <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, etc. keys as standard function keys" option is turned off in Keyboard Settings, pressing the key that is located to the right of the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key will lower the brightness, but pressing it while holding down <kbd>Fn</kbd> will trigger an <kbd>F1</kbd> keypress (and whatever <kbd>F1</kbd> might be mapped to).

Conversely, if the "Use all <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, etc. keys as standard function keys" option is turned on, the <kbd>F1</kbd> key will trigger an <kbd>F1</kbd> keypress, the <kbd>F2</kbd> an <kbd>F2</kbd> keypress, etc.

Now that I've established that, please consider the following situation.

I have an Early 2011 13" MacBook Pro. It has a Launchpad special function on the <kbd>F4</kbd> key (it looks like a 2-by-3 grid of squares), rather than the Dashboard special function like the older pre-Lion MacBooks had. However, for some strange reason, when I activate that special function, instead of showing Launchpad as expected (this is what I want) it activates Dashboard.

[image]

I am NOT asking for how to fix this problem using a walkaround, for example by mapping <kbd>F4</kbd> (the standard function key) to open Launchpad. I already know how to do that. Instead, what I'm asking is this:

**Question: How can I fix my MacBook Pro so that the Launchpad special key performed the correct function of opening Launchpad, instead of doing something else (opening Dashboard).**

*(I realize it's not a big deal and I typically use the touchpad gesture to launch Launchpad, but nonetheless I'd like to fix this if possible)*

I've reinstalled OS X Lion 10.7.3 from scratch on this MacBook, but nothing has changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24352/unmodified-f4-no-longer-summons-launchpad ...have you tried the solutions there?

Comment: I think you may be right. I just found a similar solution here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3243844?start=0&tstart=0 I'm gonna try it and report back.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately, I don't think that's it. I tried deleting that `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist` file, restarting, no luck. I've logged in to a guest account, and the Launchpad key still opens Dashboard.

Since I got this MacBook Pro used from someone, perhaps he originally had a Dashboard key and then replaced it with a Launchpad key?