# How to remap F4 to Dashboard or Notifications on a MacBook Pro in Yosemite?

Tags: keyboard, macos, system-settings, launchpad, dashboard

I had this working fine in Tiger thru Mavericks, but it broke in Yosemite. Pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> now launches Launchpad, and only <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> triggers Dashboard.

Launchpad is useless compared to Spotlight or even the Dock. I'd much rather have the <kbd>F4</kbd> key triggering Dashboard again, or even Notifications (which is really starting to come along).

I have:

- `System Prefs / Mission Control / Keyboard and Mouse Shortcuts / Show Dashboard` set to `F4`.
- `Syst Prefs / Keyboard / Keyboard / Use all F-keys as standard function keys` unticked.
- `Syst Prefs / Keyboard / Shortcuts / Launchpad & Dock / Show Launchpad` unticked.
- `Syst Prefs / Keyboard / Shortcuts / Mission Control / Show Dashboard` set to `F4`.

Ideas? Hopeless? Thanks!

2014 13" Retina MacBook Pro 
Mac OS X v10.1 Yosemite (14B25)

Comment: It sounds like everything is behaving correctly for the settings you describe.  It must be possible to do what you want [because some people have needed help to do the opposite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51506/how-come-my-launchpad-key-opens-dashboard-instead-and-how-can-i-fix-it).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any exclamation points in triangles indicating the key is also mapped to a different function? From what you’ve described as your settings, it should be working…

Comment: I know the warning icon you mean, but I don't see it on any of the Keyboard Shortcuts submenus.

Comment: Are you able to produce my desired behavior on a similar machine build?

Comment: I have this problem in High Sierra

Answer (score 1):

I have the same settings described in the message above and I don't get the Dashboard either. I have ended up assigning the top-right corner as a "hot corner" that shows the Dashboard.
System Preferences > Mission control > Hot corners (left-bottom corner of the window).

Comment: not a solution to this problem :(

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences > Mission Control > Dashboard (drop-down)
Change dashboard drop down box from "off" to either "As overlay" or "As space"

Side note: I do have Show Dashboard set as F4 as seen below in this same Mission Ctrl window. Also, I have the same settings as was mentioned in the original posted question.

Answer (score 0):

I mapped dashboard to F6 on my Mac Pro with a desktop keyboard. It doesn't require pressing the fn button since this key does not have a special use. But I think on Macbooks the F5 and F6 keys do keyboard illumination so that might not work on a laptop.